# How to programatically add a control as soon as I know parent width?

Tags: android, controls

I have a custom control inheriting from `LinearLayout` and I want to add a child control to it as soon as I know the size of this custom control.

What's the correct method to do this?

Comment: Question is not clear.  Why did you customise the LinearLayout ?

Comment: I have a custom control inheriting from `LinearLayout`. I need a container to build my stuff inside, I could inherit from something else... just need a "frame"

Comment: Post your source code

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working fine:

```
       yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                //yourView.getWidth()
                yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: onFinishInflate is not called if I add this control programatically. It's not bullet proof.

Comment: Well Im not sure if onFinishInflate() would work. adding  onPreDraw to your custom control should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override **onFinishInflate()** method inside the custom layout. That is the callback called when all views has been inflated. Use this and addd your views.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
/**
 * Great workaround to get view infos after it has been drawn
 */
mCustomView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //The code you want to run
        }
    });
```